# I can't start Next.js Application using Plesk. I get Error build module not found

Tags: next.js, hosting, plesk, nodejs-server

I tried hosting my Next js app on Plesk, but after Following this Tutorial https://dev.to/optimbro/how-to-setup-nextjs-application-on-plesk-hosting-control-panel-linux-3d54
and trying a bunch of shit myself i either get nothing happening on start -> Page just keeps endlessly loading or i get the error "Cannot find module '../build/output/log'" when i use the last step of modifying the standard command from dev to start. up to This point the build works and everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some time finding out what works and what does not work in plesk.

What I've found out:

### I do not recommend the UI for anything other than starting the App.
My steps for a successful launch are:

- Set Environment as shown in the tutorial https://dev.to/optimbro/how-to-setup-nextjs-application-on-plesk-hosting-control-panel-linux-3d54
- connect via SSH
- navigate to directory where git files are
- select desired Node environment
- run `npm run build`
- edit the `node_modules/.bin/next` You will see a defaultCommand in line 45 as `dev` change that to `start` using vim or some other editor **don't use Plesk file manager**
- then you can go to the node UI in plesk and press restart